# How do I write this in Linq to reduce code?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to reduce code, how can I use linq query to reduce number of lines in this method?

```
   private IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
        {

            var products= item.Products?.Select(x => new ProductName(x));

            if (products!= null)
            {
                foreach (var product in products)
                {
                    yield return new OutputResponse
                    {
                        Name = product.Name,
                        Description = product.Description
                    };
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: is Products a collection of ProductNames? Does a ProductName have a Name property and a constructor that takes a ProductName? I ask because all the naming seems weird/inconsistent with the types I'm guessing are involved. It would make sense to me if products had names, but selecting a new ProductName instance from a Product and then calling ProductName.Name just seems odd

Comment: Something something `SelectMany`, what have you tried?

Comment: The creation of this ProductName seems to be useless. It's just transfering Data from one loop to an other, but inside one method, this doesn't make sense. (If spread over several methods, it maybe would).

Comment: We need the classes to help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
items.SelectMany(x => x.Products ?? Array.Empty<Product>).
      .Select(x => 
            {
                var product = new ProductName(x);
                return new OutputResponse
                {
                    Name = product.Name,
                    Description = product.Description
                };
             }
```

But try to get rid of this ProductName conversion.
If it's really not possible you can also use this:

```
 items.SelectMany(x => x.Products ?? Array.Empty<Product>).
      .Select(x => new ProductName(x)) 
      .Select(product => 
                new OutputResponse
                {
                    Name = product.Name,
                    Description = product.Description
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

```
private IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{    
    var results=items.SelectMany(item=>item.Products ?? Enumerable.Empty<Product>())
                     .Select(p=>new ProductName(p))
                     .Select(pn=>new OutputResponse {    
                                      Name=pn.Name, 
                                      Description=pn.Description
                            });
    return results;
}
```

or

```
private IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{        
    var results =from item in items
                 from p in item.Products ?? Enumerable.Empty<Product>()
                 let pn=new ProductName(p)
                 select new OutputResponse {
                             Name=pn.Name,
                             Description=pn.Description
                 };
    return results;
}
```

As everyone else mentioned though, that `ProductName` seems to have no purpose.

Writing those queries requires some guessing and assumptions though, eg what each class contains, and what *Products* contains. I assume the classes involved looks something like this :

```
class OutputResponse 
{ 
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
}

class ProductName
{
    public string Name;
    public string Description;

    public ProductName(Product x)=>(Name,Description)=(x.Name,x.Description);
}

class Product
{ 
    public string Name;
    public string Description;
}

class Item
{
    public List<Product> Products;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how far you want to take it really in my opinion:

```
private IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    var products = items
        .SelectMany(x => x.Products
                .Where(p => p != null)
                .Select(p => new ProductName(p)));

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        yield return new OutputResponse
        {
            Name = product.Name,
            Description = product.Description
        };
    }
}
```

Here you can see that I've encompassed the logic in a linq statement.

I am looping through the items to get the products, looping through products to get the ones that are not `null` looping again to convert the products into product names (may want to ask yourself if this is nessasary, seeing as the information that you need to create an `OutputResponse` is on the `Product` class, could save yourself a potential looping.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Taking the https://stackoverflow.com/a/59844773/637968 even further:

```
private IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items)
{
    return items.SelectMany(x => x.Products ?? Array.Empty<Product>)
                .Select(x => new ProductName(x))
                .Select(p => new OutputResponse() { Name = product.Name, Description = product.Description});
}
```

It will iterate twice over the whole collection but OP asked for LOC reduction and not performance improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following,

```
private static IEnumerable<OutputResponse> GetOutput(IEnumerable<Item> items) {
     return items.SelectMany(x => x.Products)?.Select(x=> new OutputResponse() { Name = new ProductName(x).Name, Description = new ProductName(x).Description });
}
```